# Dynamically populating Ajax data attribute with object that matches MVC PartialViewResult signatures

Tags: javascript, c#, ajax, asp.net-mvc-4

I need to populate the ajax data attribute with one or many key value pairs to post up to a MVC controller action. The snag is that I want to use one js function to send data to different controller actions each with different signatures. Here goes:

MVC View

```
@{ 
    var Params = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
    {
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param1","foo"),
        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("param2","bar"),
    };

    var targetUrl = "/MyActionName/";
    var myParams = @Json.Encode(Params);
    var clickFunction = $"myFunction('{targetUrl}', {myParams})";
}

<a href="#" onclick="@(clickFunction)">Do It</a>
```

Javascript function

```
function myFunction(url, paramData) {

    var dataParams = [];
    paramData.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
        var key = arrayItem.Key;
        var value = arrayItem.Value;

        dataParams[key] = value;
    });

    // This works 
    $.ajax({
         url: url,
         data: {
             param1: "foo",
             param2: "bar"
         },
         success: function (partialViewResult) {
             $('#TargetDIV').html(partialViewResult);
         },
     });

     // This doesn't
     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         data: { dataParams },
         success: function (partialViewResult) {
             $('#TargetDIV').html(partialViewResult);
         },
     });
 }
```

Controller Action Example 1

```
public PartialViewResult MyAction1(string param1, string param2)
{
....
}
```

Controller Action Example 2

```
public PartialViewResult MyAction2(string apple, string orange, string grape)
{
....
}
```

Controller Action Example 3

```
public PartialViewResult MyAction3(string pig, string cow, string dog, string cat)
{
....
}
```

I'd like myFunction to be used to post up to multiple controller actions with varying signatures. So i'd just need to throw a list of KeyValuePair at myFunction and will handle it.

Tried so far without any luck:

1. using JSON.stringify but is doesn't format dataParams in the correct way.
2. using a MVC model instead of many separate params. This is because the param names will be different so one model won't fit all scenarios

If I can get this to work i'd then extend it to handle data types other than `string` but for sake of simplicity i've stuck to `string` here

Any help would be very much appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is wrong dataParams you must to set is as an object

```
function myFunction(url, paramData) {

    var dataParams = {};
    paramData.forEach(function (arrayItem) {
        var key = arrayItem.Key;
        var value = arrayItem.Value;

        dataParams[key] = value;
    });

    // This works 
    $.ajax({
         url: url,
         data: {
             param1: "foo",
             param2: "bar"
         },
         success: function (partialViewResult) {
             $('#TargetDIV').html(partialViewResult);
         },
     });

     // This doesn't
     $.ajax({
         url: url,
         data: dataParams,
         success: function (partialViewResult) {
             $('#TargetDIV').html(partialViewResult);
         },
     });
 }
```

Comment: Nice one Ciccio! I was blinded by all my previous attempts to try this. Worked perfectly